# I rooted my phone. Now apps cannot connect to the internet but browsers work fine

Tags: rooting, internet, connection-issues, unrooting

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y and rooted it a few days ago. After that I set up a few apps and granted them access to root permissions (via the Superuser app). I allowed root to all apps that requested it.

Now I cannot connect to the internet via any app except browser apps - Gmail cannot receive emails, and Google Play is not loading.

I tried a factory reset and unrooted the phone, but it is still not working.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: what rooted apps did you use?

Comment: Don't have enough rep to post this as an answer, but this may be resolved by disabling any proxy settings on your WiFi connection: http://www.reddit.com/r/LGG3/comments/2ofhsn/rooted_with_stump_root_now_no_data_connections/

Answer (score 3):

Is background data enabled?

You can enable it in `Settings->Accounts and Sync->Background Data` or `System Settings->Data Use->Menu Button->Auto-sync data checked`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's specific to your Google accounts, check the general Google synce settings.

```
Settings->Accounts/Google->YourEmail@gmail.com Last synced MM/DD/YYYY 12:00 PM->List of Google Sync Settings.
```

Some apps may indicate sync is turned off, like the Gmail app:

```
Gmail App->Menu/Settings->YourEmail@gmail.com->DATA USAGE/Gmail sync is OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue with whatsapp, finally found out the simple solution

`Settings -> Accounts & sync -> ENABLE this`