# Internet Apps are not working but browser works just fine and i am able to access websites

Tags: connection-issues

I have a rooted AT&T HTC inspire 4G handset, i am not able to use any internet apps but i am able to use the in build browsers to access internet over a WiFi.

I tried creating  hotspot and share that internet with this HTC phone and everything worked just fine all the Apps and internet.

Please help me with this, I did tried syncing background data, and WiFi proxy setting, but No luck yet.

Comment: We've already got this questions a couple of times here. Please check: [connection issues - Apps can't connect to internet](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36377/16575), [rooting - I rooted my phone. Now apps cannot connect to the internet but browsers work fine](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34379/16575), and also follow the links of your tags (e.g. "internet") for further possible solutions. The "Related" section of this page also might hold something useful.

Comment: Amrit did you get a solution for the problem you raised?

Answer (score 0):

That's a stumper - have you tried calling up your carrier and making sure that it's not an issue with them?

Have you installed any permissions privacy management apps?  They might be blocking internet connectivity by default.

Failing that, the only suggestion I would be able to make is to do a full factory reset... not very appealing, I know.

Comment: Thanks Logos for the quick response, well actually its my office phone,I have rooted this phone and the only other apps i see are BusyBox installer,Teeter & Superuser. The weird thing is that with my office Wifi i am able to access internet not apps,

Answer (score 0):

Quote OP's comment:

> Thanks Logos for the quick response, well actually its my office phone,I have rooted this phone and the only other apps i see are BusyBox installer,Teeter & Superuser. The weird thing is that with my office Wifi i am able to access internet not apps, –  Amrit Jan 7 at 10:56

It could be because your office WiFi may be blocking that apps. (Eg: Facebook)

Answer (score 0):

Solution which worked for me is by installing the configuration settings. Call up the customer care and ask them send you the configuration settings. Since you reset your phone old configuration settings would have been erased. Once you install the configuration settings you will be able to access internet for all the apps.

Answer (score 0):

**DELETE HOSTS FILE**

For advanced users only and for rooted Android devices.

- Open File Manager App.
- Browse to `/system/etc`.
- Delete `hosts.txt` file